# Characterization of the law of a stochastic process by its finite dimensional distributions

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ a probability space. Let $(X_t)_{t \in [0,T]}$, $(Y_t)_{t \in [0,T]}$ (real-valued) centered Gaussian processes such that the finite dimensional distributions coincide, i.e.
>
> $$\mathbb{E}X_t = \mathbb{E}Y_t = 0 \qquad \qquad C(s,t) := \mathbb{E}(X_s \cdot X_t) = \mathbb{E}(Y_s \cdot Y_t)$$
>
> Moreover, assume that the trajectories $t \mapsto X(t,\omega)$, $t \mapsto Y(t,\omega)$ are in $L^2([0,T])$ for all $w \in \Omega$.
>
> Does the equality
>
> $$\mathbb{P}(\|X-\varphi\|_{L^2}<\delta) = \mathbb{P}(\|Y-\varphi\|_{L^2}<\delta) := \mathbb{P} \left\{\omega; \left(\int_0^T |Y(t,\omega)-\varphi(t)|^2 \, dt \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} < \delta \right\}$$ hold for $\varphi \in L^2([0,T]), \delta>0$? Equivalently: Do the distributions of the mappings
>
> $$\Omega \ni \omega \mapsto X(\cdot,\omega) \in L^2([0,T]) \qquad \Omega \ni \omega \mapsto Y(\cdot,\omega) \in L^2([0,T]) \tag{1}$$
>
> on $L^2([0,T])$, endowed with the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra generated by the $L^2$-norm, coincide?

Using the definition of the finite dimensional distributions (and Kolmogorov's extension theorem), it's not difficult to see that the distributions of the mappings in $(1)$ coincide with respect to the product-$\sigma$-algebra on $L^2([0,T])$.

Right from the intuition, I would say, that the open balls $B(\varphi,\delta)$ are not contained in the product-$\sigma$-algebra, because I need the information about the whole path to decide whether it is an element of this ball - consequently, this approach does not work out.

I would appreciate any hints & suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Some comments first. Notation is a bit confusing: you assume that for any fixed $\omega$, it holds that $X(\cdot,\omega) \in L^2([0,T])$ and the same for $Y$, right? So far it is a bit unclear: you use both $t\mapsto X(\cdot,\omega)$ and $\omega\mapsto X(\cdot,\omega)$. I would suggest you using $t\mapsto X(t,\omega)$ when you talk about $X$ as a function of $t$ for a fixed $\omega$, and vice-versa. For example, $\omega\mapsto X(t,\omega)$ is usually considered to be a function of $\omega$ and hence cannot belong to $L^2([0,T])$ - rather you shall talk e.g. about $L^2(\Omega)$.

Comment: The second comment is: what do you mean by the `product-$\sigma$-algebra on $L^2([0,T])$`? The latter space does not have a natural product structure, in contrast e.g. to $\Bbb R^{[0,T]}$. If you mean the $\sigma$-algebra on $L^2([0,T])$ induced from the product one on $\Bbb R^{[0,T]}$, then to start with, I don't think that $L^2([0,T])$ is a measurable subset of the latter space. Finally, KET alone does not seem to provide an existence of $\Bbb P$ on $L^2([0,T])$ due to the same arguments.

Comment: @Ilya You are right, I corrected it. I hope it's clearer now. Concerning the product-$\sigma$-algebra: I mean the trace-$\sigma$-algebra of the product $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^{[0,T]}$.

Comment: W.r.t. correction: what about $\omega\mapsto X(\cdot,\omega)$ in $(1)$? W.r.t. $\sigma$-algebra: is $L^2([0,T]) \in \mathcal F$ where by the latter I mean the product $\sigma$-algebra on $\Bbb R^{[0,T]}$?

Comment: @Ilya By $\omega \mapsto X(\cdot,\omega)$ I mean that each $w \in \Omega$ is mapped to its path $[t \mapsto X(t,\omega)]$... and by assumption this path is an element of $L^2([0,T])$. Concerning your other question: I don't think so, but nevertheless $L^2([0,T]) \cap \mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $L^2([0,T])$.

Comment: Remember that $L^2$ is a space of equivalence classes of functions, so you can't talk about evaluations on particular points (i.e f(t)). For the same reason you can't see it as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{[0,T]}$. Now if the trayectories are in some nice space such as $C[0,T]$ or $D[0,T]$ then the event $\{\|X_t - \phi \|_2 < \delta\}$ is product-measurable since the product $\sigma$-algebra coincides with the borelian sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}^{[0,T]}$ and the function $ \| \cdot - \phi \|_2$ is continuous and hence measurable.

Comment: To support the point of @Bunder I was going to say the following: even if $L^2$ would be a subset of $\Bbb R^{[0,T]}$ without being measurable, KET only would give you the existence of the measure on the latter space, and without measurability of $L^2$ you would not be able to restrict $\Bbb P$ to the trace $\sigma$-algebra of $L^2$. What is usually done in such case, is indeed to construct a process on a better space. For example, after applying KET you e.g. try using Kolmogorov continuity theorem to construct the process with the *same* FDD on $C([0,T])$.

Comment: In the current setting of the question, again, you shall focus on the formal construction of $\Bbb P$ on $L^2$ (or e.g. $L^2\cap C$) from finite-dimensional distributions. So far this very core for the question step is omitted.

Comment: Please tell me, whether the issue is clear to you, or shall I elaborate on it?

Comment: @Ilya Actually, this is where my question is coming from. In the proof (which I would like to understand), they construct a Gaussian process $Y$ with continuous sample paths such it has the same fdd's as $X$. Afterwards, they claim that $$\mathbb{P}(\|X-\varphi\|_2<\delta) = \mathbb{P}(\|Y-\varphi\|_2<\delta)$$ and use some nice properties of $Y$ to calculate this probability. But I still don't see the point - Why can I simply replace $X$ by a "better" process?

Comment: Don't I need that $X$ is already sufficiently nice (i.e. such that $\{w; \|X(\cdot,w)-\varphi\|_2<\delta\}$ is measurable wrt to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the product-$\sigma$-algebra) in any case...?

Comment: For sure, you need the latter set to be measurable, otherwise the LHS is simply undefined. I also think it's better if you provide a source, since so far the situation is the following. Given fdd's we can construct a *unique* distribution $\Bbb P_1$ on $(\Bbb R^{[0,T]},\mathscr F)$. Now, your constraint that $X(\cdot,\omega)\in L^2$ means that we have to construct the distribution either on $L^2$ directly, or on the former space in such a way that non-$L^2$ elements of $(\Bbb R^{[0,T]},\mathscr F)$ are $\Bbb P_1$-null. Here by $L^2$ I mean $L^2\cap \Bbb R^{[0,T]}$ (abusing notation a bit)

Comment: ...now, in the first case, we need some theorem that would tell us that it is possible to construct a distribution, say $\Bbb P_2$ on $L^2$ - whose meant $\sigma$-algebra, btw, is not very clear so far. In the second case, we also need some non-trivial conditions on fdd's to guarantee that bad elements are $\Bbb P_1$-null, since the latter is uniquely defined by fdd's. That's just to satisfy the constraint - so the construction of $X$ has to be somehow clarified in your book/paper, cause so far it is unclear how exactly it is done (which is not obvious and very important).

Comment: ...so, without the precise construction of $X$ it's hard to say whether the current formulation of the question is perfectly formal, as it allows for the several interpretations. For example, if fdd's are nice enough, nothing prevents us from constructing $X$ directly on $C$ using [KCT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_continuity_theorem) rather than on product spaces with product $\sigma$-algebras.